# Validate pandas.Period with Pandera schema

Tags: python, pandas, period, pandera

I have a dataframe with a column "Period" which should have a dtype of pandas.Period.

I would like to validate this, using a Pandera Schema (either DataFrameModel or DataFrameSchema).

My attempts so far return errors.

If I try the code below, then I get an error

```
Data type '<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.period.Period'>' not understood by Engine.
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandera as pa
from pandera.typing import Series


class Schema(pa.DataFrameModel):
   period: Series[pd.Period]


df = pd.DataFrame({"period" : pd.period_range("31/01/2024", "31/12/2024", freq='M')})

Schema.validate(df)
```

Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to use `PeriodDtype`;
2. `PeriodDtype` takes a parameter `freq`, that needs to be specified using `typing.Annotated`:

```
from typing import Annotated

class Schema(pa.DataFrameModel):
    period: Series[Annotated[pd.PeriodDtype, "M"]]  # <= change this

df = pd.DataFrame({"period": pd.period_range("31/01/2024", "31/12/2024", freq="M")})
```

You can read more about it [here](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dataframe_models.html#parametrized-dtypes).

Answer (score 0):

> can you check this solution

```
import pandas as pd
import pandera as pa
from pandera import Column, Check
def is_period(series): return series.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, pd.Period)).all()
schema = pa.DataFrameSchema({ "period": Column(object, checks=Check(is_period)), })
df = pd.DataFrame({"period": pd.period_range("31/01/2024", "31/12/2024", freq='M')})
schema.validate(df)
```